# Populate dropdownlist using stored proc based on user logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm just learning asp.net so I may be wrong on how I'm doing this so let me know if there is a better way.

I have a "portal", where a user logs in and then they have a dropdownlist of all their sites they manage.

I want to populate the dropdown box using a stored proc I created which is based on the user logged in.

I used the built in createuserWizard which stores the users in the database. I created another table that has all the sites and a 3rd table to link the sites and users together.

Here is the dropdown list

```
<code>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListAClient" runat="server" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSitePicker" DataTextField="SiteName" 
         DataValueField="SiteName">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSitePicker" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainAppDB %>"
         SelectCommand="portal_SitePicker" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">

         <SelectParameters>
               <asp:Parameter Name="portaluserid" Type="String" />
         </SelectParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</code>
```

Here is the code for the stored procedure

```
<code>
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[portal_SitePicker]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @portaluserid varchar 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT SiteName
FROM dbo.aspnet_UserMap, dbo.Sites 
WHERE dbo.Sites.SiteID = dbo.aspnet_UserMap.SiteID
and dbo.aspnet_UserMap.UserID = @portaluserid
END
</code>
```

If I test the stored proc it pulls the correct sites, but I'm not sure how to get the userid value from the current logged in user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Page.User.Identity.Name` will get you the current logged-in username.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my StoredProc to use the username instead of ID. I also added <asp:FormParameter FormField="Page.User.Identity.Name" Name="portaluserid" Type="String" /> to my sqldatasource. Yet when the page loads, the drop downbox is empty. I must be missing a step.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the parameter, it is beeter to set the length for you parameter for varchar in SQL and the asp page. You may try to  add the size on the parmeter like tht  on the asp page
 and @portaluserid varchar (25) and store procedure